# How can I manually save and restore configuration for ISO bootings?

Tags: boot, configuration, iso

From time to time I boot from ISO files saved in my hard disk. It boots and executes much faster than the live-cd. I would like to save a minimum configuration so that I don't have to configure it each time. I tried "rsync -av" the user's home and then compressing it to bz2, but it didn't work well. When I extracted the bz2 it gave me a few errors, even though I copied the extracted files to replace the user's home but somethings were not configures and the most strange thing was that .gvfs directory appeared without "w" permission for the owner (that is 500). To my surprise not even root can chmod it nor write anything in there. I don't know the reason, maybe I have to do the backup and/or the restoring of files from out the user.

I would like to save mainly:
keyboard layout config
mouse and touchpad configs
wireless settings
browser's bookhemarks
and a few other programs (like terminal) configurations

so that I can easily configure the system the next time I boot from exactly the same ISO file.

What I did was:

```
rsync -av /home/ubuntu /media/BACKUP (which is a different partition)
and then

tar -jcvf /media/BACKUP/ubuntu-isoconfig.bz2 /media/BACKUP/ubuntu
```

and then extract with the archive manager and replace with rsync.

Just, for the record, the .gvsf/ directory behaviour:

```
$ ls -dl .gvfs/
dr-x------ 2 ubuntu ubuntu 0 ene 26 14:43 .gvfs/

$ sudo chmod 700 .gvfs
chmod: cannot access `.gvfs': Permission denied
```

...............

mikewhatever: I have skiped .gvfs and after restoring the original home directory, I only see the backgrouns, the folders and firefox bookmarks restored, NOT THE KEYBOARD nor the network manager sttings which I have done without root permits.

Comment: If there is a problem with booting from an ISO, as indicated by the title, you should add the relevant grub entry to the question. Otherwise, I'd suggest rethinking the title.

Answer (score 1):

You should exclude `.gvfs` from the backup by using `--exclude .gvfs`. [GVFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS) is a virtual file system used for mounting Windows shares.

There is also no need to chmod it, as the output you got from `ls -dl .gvfs/` looks correct.

Comment: I still don't see how to save an load the settings from the default user account.

Answer (score 0):

what you might looking for is persistence file

an easy way to create setup that you need is utility named UNetbootin available through official repositories

to install it type in the terminal
   `sudo apt-get install unetbootin`

Comment: People call "persistence" a way to save your changes/settings in live boots, but for what I have seen that intends to load the settings automatically. I don't need that, something manual would be better than  reading dozens of tutorials to see how could I adapt that to iso bootings.

Comment: Unetbootin= installer of Linux/BSD distributions to a partition or USB drive. 
UNetbootin allows for the installation of various Linux/BSD distributions to a
 partition or USB drive, so it's no different from a standard install, only it
 doesn't need a CD. It can create a dual-boot install, or replace the existing
 OS entirely. It doesn't seem like an answer to what I am asking.